# How to monitor a local file for changes, apply a RegEx replace on it and save/overwrite to a destination file?

Tags: files, scripts, regex

I'd like to start a script or something that watches a text file for changes. When the file changes I want to run it through a RegEx parser to replace some text and then output the modified file to a destination file.

I'm pretty new to Linux so bear with me but this would be cool to get sorted so thanks for your help in advance...

Comment: is this not possible? :(

Comment: look into `incron`. it's like `cron` except instead of being triggered by times, it's triggered by filesystem events. you could run a `grep` when your file's changed.

Answer (score 3):

Before using this script install inotify-tools (`sudo apt-get install inotify-tools`).

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE=/path/to/monitored/file
DSTFILE=/path/to/destination/file
SEARCH="Text you want to replace"
REPLACE="Text that will replace the one in SEARCH"

while inotifywait -e modify $FILE; do
  sed "s/$SEARCH/$REPLACE/g" $FILE > $DSTFILE
done
```